# How to reading Blob on Google App Engine remotely?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to process some uploaded files on Google App Engine using the `remote_api_shell.py`.

I have tried:

```
python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\remote_api_shell.py" -s <your_app_id>.appspot.com
```

and login successfully.

But there is no information on the Internet tell me how to show all uploaded files.

I wonder **how to show all Blobinfo?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the [blobstore api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass) in the shell.
For example:

```
>>> from google.appengine.ext.blobstore import BlobInfo
>>> qry = BlobInfo.all()
>>> for f in qry:
...     print f.filename
```